# Has Israel denied visas to high-level UN personnel before?

Tags: israel, united-nations, visa

Politico [writes](https://www.politico.eu/article/israel-denies-visa-united-nations-under-secretary-general-martin-griffiths-antonio-guterres-hamas-conflict/)

> Israel’s U.N. ambassador Gilad Erdan told Israeli radio on Wednesday morning that the country has denied a visa to U.N. Under Secretary-General Martin Griffiths, following Guterres’ comments.

Have there been cases before when Israel denied visas to high-level UN personnel?

Comment: Does non-renewal of OHCHR country director's visa count? https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/10/16/israel-stops-issuing-visas-to-un-human-rights-workers Before anyone says "don't answer in the comment", I'm not sure if country director is "high-level", and whether denying is equal to non-renewing

Comment: @Martheen: it seems a reasonable example since it appears it was retaliation for something OHCHR did. Of course I left the terms somewhat ambiguous in the Q because I didn't know of that event. "High-level" was meant to exclude them denying visa to some UNRWA staff for some mundane reason, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified in the comment, there's at least one instance in 2020 where Israel suspended the relationship with OHCHR and [chose to not renew their foreign staff's visa](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/10/16/israel-stops-issuing-visas-to-un-human-rights-workers), forcing them to leave, including the country director. The suspension is retaliation for OHCHR [publishing lists of companies](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-51477231) working in illegal settlements in the West Bank.  While Israel also [suspended](https://www.un.org/unispal/document/auto-insert-187895/) their relationship with OHCHR in 2012, I can't find if there was any visa denial, revocation, or non-renewal during that spat.